# Return smalldatetime value from scalar function SELECT query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking to create a scalar function in SQL Server (2017) that leverages a calendar table I built awhile back in order to calculate and return a date a given number of business days forward in time from a given date.  I have been struggling with how to pass the `SMALLDATETIME` return value back appropriately.  To give some idea what I'm attempting:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.AddBusDaysToDate
(
   @startDate SMALLDATETIME,
   @numBusDays INT,
)
RETURNS SMALLDATETIME
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @rs SMALLDATETIME;

   SELECT @rs = TOP(1) dt
   FROM (
        SELECT TOP(@numBusDays) dt
        FROM dbo.OurCalendar
        WHERE isWeekday = 1
        AND isHoliday = 0
        AND dt >= @startDate
        ORDER BY dt ASC
    ) as ID
    ORDER BY dt DESC

    RETURN @rs
END
```

`dt` is a `SMALLDATETIME` data type on our calendar table.

The query itself runs as intended when values plugged in for the variables, but I was trying to repurpose a similar function that calculated the difference in business days between two points on the calendar, with a different data type.  So I'm unsure if I'm pulling in a row to the @rs instead of the individual value, or how to separate/isolate that specific 'cell' from the SELECT query result.  I expect I'm probably missing something very simple.

Any help or a point in the right direction would be very well appreciated.

Comment: FYI databases don't have a concept of "cell" they have rows and columns.

Comment: On dbo.OurCalendar, dt is a column of data type smalldatetime.  I see multiple 'incorrect syntax' errors, beginning at TOP(1), along with "Select statements included within a function cannot return data to a client."  I would like to use the function to query the top @numBusDays rows, and then grab the smalldatetime value from the dt column of the last row, since this method allows me to bypass weekends and company holidays.

Comment: Ignore me... I was getting confused. You aren't aliasing anything incorrectly. Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results. Its unclear to me what you are trying to do and what is/isn't working about that.

Comment: Your previous suggestion was helpful!  I was able to get it without aliasing, but I had to add the sub-query to capture the numBusDays argument passed in.  I think I have it working as intended now.  As I'm still relatively new here, should I post the code on a new reply or edit my original post to update?

Comment: I just realised that was just a typo... `@rs = TOP(1) dt` should have been `TOP(1) @rs = dt`

Comment: Why would a "calendar" use smalldatetime? Date seems the most appropriate datatype. And apparently you've never had a business close because of some emergency - like a fire evacuation, snowstorm, loss of power, etc. Your logic is "work day" = "week day" and not "holiday". Think about that carefully.

Comment: I understand your point and agree that Date seems the most appropriate datatype, but I have had to work around pre-existing logic.  The function is being used to set target due dates and the business only cares about subtracting weekends and planned holidays which have been built into the calendar table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve with the following:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.AddBusDaysToDate
(
    @startDate SMALLDATETIME,
    @numBusDays INT,
)
RETURNS SMALLDATETIME
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @rs SMALLDATETIME;
   DECLARE @workdayModifier INT;

   IF EXISTS (
      SELECT dt FROM dbo.OurCalendar 
      WHERE dt = @startDate 
      AND isWeekday = 1 
      AND isHoliday = 0
      )
   SET @workdayModifier = 1
   ELSE
   SET @workdayModifier = 0


   SELECT TOP(1) @rs = dt
       FROM (
           SELECT TOP(@numBusDays + @workdayModifier) dt
           FROM dbo.OurCalendar
           WHERE isWeekday = 1
           AND isHoliday = 0
           AND dt >= @startDate
           ORDER BY dt ASC
       ) as ID
       ORDER BY dt DESC
   
   RETURN @rs    

END
```